# Java Swing : How to invoke stopCellEditing() before TreeListeners:valueChanged?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, event-dispatching

This is a follow-up to these earlier questions:

- [How to stop editing with DefaultCellEditor when a separate JBtton is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377924/how-to-stop-editing-with-defaultcelleditor-when-a-separate-jbtton-is-pressed)
- [Sun Bug 4724980: JTable: Add API to control what happens to edits when table loses focus.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4724980)

When I use the `terminateEditOnFocusLost` property, like below, my CellEditor correctly stops editing when the table loses focus:

```
jtable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

It also works with my JButtons. The `stopCellEditing()` method is called for my TableCellEditor *before* the button press action is processed. But when I use it with a JTree, and the tree selection changes, the `TreeSelectionListener.valueChanged` method is called *before* `stopCellEditing()`.

Does any one know if there is a way to force `stopCellEditing()` to be invoked first, or should I just make up some work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`JTree` does not have similar client property in `Swing`. 
But `JXTree`, a derived class from `JTree`, in `SwingX` does: `invokeStopEditing`.

If you can't use `SwingX`, you can always look at the source code of `JXTree` and see how this StopEditing mecanism works: [`JXTree SwingX 1.0 API Documentation and Javadoc`](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTree.html) `(go to Source tab)`

Specially, starting from line `974`, a listener is created to monitor "`permanentFocusOwner`" property change on the `KeyboardFocusManager` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your question with regards to the `TreeSelectionListener` and how it relates to the timing `stopCellEditing()` method being called. Are you creating a custom `TreeCellEditor`? If so, some more info on the setup of this editor would be useful.

However, you also referenced an earlier item which pertained to cell editing on a `JTable`, its loss of focus to an outside component, and the affect of this on the editing cell. I have taken that as a hint that you would like a similiar solution for `JTree`...

---

As noted, `JTree` does not implement the handling of the property for `"terminateEditOnFocusLost"` out of the box.  This doesn't mean that you can do it yourself.

Looking at the code for `JTable`, it is pretty straight forward.  A class is put together whose only job is to identify if the `JTree` still has focus when there is a focus change, and if not, it calls `stopEditing()` and if that fails it calls `cancelEditing()`.  Here it is, adapted for a tree:

```
class CellEditorRemover implements PropertyChangeListener {
    KeyboardFocusManager focusManager;
    public CellEditorRemover(KeyboardFocusManager fm) {
        this.focusManager = fm;
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent ev) {
        if (!tree.isEditing() || 
          tree.getClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost") != Boolean.TRUE) 
        {
          return;
        }

        Component c = focusManager.getPermanentFocusOwner();
        while (c != null) {
            if (c == tree) { // focus remains inside the tree
                return;
            } else if ((c instanceof Window)
                        || (c instanceof Applet && c.getParent() == null)) 
            {
                if (c == SwingUtilities.getRoot(tree)) {
                    if (!tree.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing()) {
                        tree.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            c = c.getParent();
        }
    }
}
```

You will note that your tree has to be accessible somehow to this class.  There are a couple setup calls to perform to make this work:

```
tree.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
KeyboardFocusManager fm = 
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
editorRemover = new CellEditorRemover(fm);
fm.addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", editorRemover);
```

This should have the added benefit of making your `JTree` behave the same way that your `JTable` behaves when you press a `JButton`.