# Setting custom property for Swing Components (JEditorPane)

Tags: java, swing

I am working in a Twitter feed application using Java Swing.

is it possible for me to set custom attribute to the JEditorPane as like below

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
jep.tweetID = "222";
jep.tweetText = "Good Day...";
```

so that i can get these attributes directly in events associated with this JEditorPane like below

```
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {
                   String currentTweetID = e.getSource().tweetID;
         }
```

if this is possible, please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every AWT Component, which Swing components are built on, has a `setName` method and a `getName` method.  You can name your component with any String, like your `tweetID`.  If you need other identification strings, you can concatenate them together and use the `setName` method to pass them to your action methods.

You can get the text of your `JEditorPane` with the `getText` method.

Comment: Cool.. actually i tried to set and use Tooltip.. get/set name is good option though..

Comment: Also consider `putClientProperty()` & `getClientProperty()` in `JComponent`.

Comment: @trashgod: I never noticed those methods.  How do you pass the keys around so the listener knows which property to get?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: That's a perennial problem; some are [buried in the source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/377924/230513); some are [vendor-specific](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html); for  local use, a package-access constant may do.

Comment: @trashgod thank you for sharing that. You should really make that an answer rather than a comment. It was very helpful to me in eliminating a race condition.

Comment: @CardinalSystem: Glad it helped, but be sure to verify correct synchronization; one approach is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I didn't mean to say race condition. That was my initial diagnosis, but later debugging revealed a different issue which required a flag to be present on the JComponent. Nevertheless, thank you for the link! It's a very helpful read.

Answer (score 1):

All instances of [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html) offer support for component-specific properties accessible via [`putClientProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) and [`getClientProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty(java.lang.Object)). Common use cases include layout constraints and GUI hints such as `sizeVariant`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

Notes:

- The API warns "The `clientProperty` dictionary is not intended to support large scale extensions," and a separate *view_model* may be warranted.
- Existing keys may be documented poorly, perhaps [buried in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377924/230513) or [evanescent, vendor-specific features](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html).